# Undefined Index Error when using variable in if statement that is sometimes not set

Tags: php

I use this if statement but sometimes `$_GET['av']` is not set. When it is not set it throws an error. Is there a way around this?

```
if ($admin == 1 AND ($_GET['av'] == "0" OR !isset($_GET['av'])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, just place the second statement first.

```
if ($admin == 1 AND (!isset($_GET['av']) OR $_GET['av'] == "0"))
```

That way, if `$_GET['av']` isn't set, your code will never end up referencing it, the if-statement will be stopped at `isset` and the block just won't execute because of a false return value.

Also check out [Demorgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) and how it applies to if statements. That might help clarify the formatting of more complicated statements.

Comment: I thought I had tried that but I got the same error, but just used your answer and it worked.

Comment: My logic is correct in what I am trying to do, all I had to do was reverse the order as you said with the original answer

Comment: well your logic currently returns true if the first statement is true and `$_GET['av']` is zero or isn't set. Except that when it's not set and your try to reference it with `$_GET['av']`, you get your error.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are saying the same thing but this is what works `$admin == 1 AND (!isset($_GET['av']) OR $_GET['av'] == "0")`

Comment: if I don't use `!isset` and use `isset` instead then it will return true at times when I don't want it to be true

Comment: first of all, you check out [Demorgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) and see how it applues to if statements. But what you posted would work if you want your loop to execute if `$admin` equals 1 and either '$_GET['av']' is false or null or it is equal to zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61646/discussion-between-wold-and-michael-st-clair).